# Pythonic way to handle complex nested dict structures

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

My codebase relies on managing data thats currently in a very deeply nested dictionary. Example:

```
    'USA': {
        'Texas': {
            'Austin': {
                '2017-01-01': 169,
                '2017-02-01': 231
            },
            'Houston': {
                '2017-01-01': 265,
                '2017-02-01': 310
            }
        }
```

This extends for multiple countries, states/regions, cities, and dates.

I encounter a problem when trying to access values since I need to have a deeply nested for-loop to iterate over each country, state, city, and date to apply some kind of operation. I'm looking for some kind of alternative.

1. Assuming the nested dict structure is the same, is there an alternative to so many loops? Perhaps using map, reduce or lambda?
2. Is there a better way to store all of this data without using nested dicts?

Comment: have you look to pandas??

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Second question - have you considered [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Pandas `DataFrame` object ([Pandas Dataframe Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)), that can store your data in a tabular format, similar to a spreadsheet. In that case, your `DataFrame` should have a column to represent each key in your nested data (one column for Country, another for State, and so on).

Pandas `DataFrames` also accounts for filtering, grouping and another useful operations based on your records (rows) for each column. Let's say you want to filter your data to return only the rows from Texas that happened after '2018-02-01' (`df` is your `DataFrame`). This could be achieved with something like this:

`df[df['State'] == 'Texas' & df['Date'] > '2018-02-01']`

To build these `DataFrame` objects, you could start from your data formatted as a collection of records:

```
data = [['USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-01-01', 169],
['USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-02-01', 231],
['USA', 'Texas', 'Houston', '2017-01-01', 265],
['USA', 'Texas', 'Houston', '2017-02-01', 310]]
```

and then build them like this:

`df = DataFrame(data, columns=['Country', 'State', 'City', 'Date', 'Value'])`

If `DataFrame` objects are not an option, and you do not want to use nested loops, you could also access inner data using list comprehensions with nested predicates and filters:

```
[
   d[country][state][city][date]
   for country in d.keys()
   for state in d[country].keys()
   for city in d[country][state].keys()
   for date in d[country][state][city].keys()
   if country == 'USA' and state == 'Texas' and city == 'Houston'
]
```

However, I can not see much difference in that approach over the nested loops, and there is a penalty in code readability, imho.

Using the collection of records approach pointed earlier (`data`), instead of a nested structure, you could filter your rows using:

```
[r for r in data if r[2] == 'Houston']
```

For improved readability, you could use a list of `namedtuple` objects as your list of records. Your data would be:

```
from collections import namedtuple
record = namedtuple('Record', 'country state city date value')
data = [
   record('USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-01-01', 169),
   record('USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-02-01', 231),
   record('USA', 'Texas', 'Houston', '2017-01-01', 265),
   record('USA', 'Texas', 'Houston', '2017-02-01', 310)
]
```

and your filtering would be improved, eg.:

*Getting specific records*

```
[r for r in data if r.city == 'Houston']
```

returning

```
[
    Record(country='USA', state='Texas', city='Houston', date='2017-01-01', value=265),
    Record(country='USA', state='Texas', city='Houston', date='2017-02-01', value=310)
]
```

*Getting only the values for those specific records*

```
[r.value for r in data if r.city == 'Houston']
```

returning

```
[265, 310]
```

This last approach can also deal with custom object instances, considering that `namedtuple` objects can store them easily.

Comment: One thing I forgot to clarify, sometimes the value in the dict may not actually be data. For example, we sometimes store an initialized object there instead, so dataframes wouldn't work.

Comment: @halfcup I updated my answer considering this new situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, implementing overloading methods, and use recursion:

```
d = {'USA': {
    'Texas': {
        'Austin': {
            '2017-01-01': 169,
            '2017-02-01': 231
        },
        'Houston': {
            '2017-01-01': 265,
            '2017-02-01': 310
        }
      }
   }
 }
class StateData:
   def __init__(self, structure):
      self.structure = structure
      self.levels = {'country':0, 'state':1, 'city':2, 'date':3}
   def get_level(self, d, target, current= 0):
      total_listing = [((a, b) if target == 3 else a) if current == target else self.get_level(b, target, current + 1) for a, b in d.items()] 
      return [i for b in total_listing for i in b] if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in total_listing) else total_listing
   def __getitem__(self, val):
       return self.get_level(self.structure, self.levels[val])

s = StateData(d)
print(s['city'])
print(s['date'])
```

Output:

```
['Austin', 'Houston']
[('2017-01-01', 169), ('2017-02-01', 231), ('2017-01-01', 265), ('2017-02-01', 310)]
```

It may be best to store your data as a list of lists, which will then make it possible for you to group according to the needs of each individual operation. For instance:

```
state_data = [['USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-01-01', 169],
              ['USA', 'Texas', 'Austin', '2017-02-01', 231],
              ['USA', 'Houston', '2017-01-01', 265],
              ['USA', 'Houston', '2017-02-01', 310]]
```

Answer (score -2):

There's also [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10).

It allows you to flatten a dict into a pandas dataframe like this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

d = json.load(f)

# Parent node of dict d is 'programs'
n = json_normalize(d['programs'])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes